# Carryover List Numbering into my Table

Tags: html

I'm wanting to do number of the table based on the parent li number. I have done decimal numbering with JQuery but I was wondering if it is possible to pass that into a table? So like my example but not having me manually put the 1.1 1.2 2.1 2.2 etc.

```
<ol>
    <li>Item1
        <table>
            <tr><th>Num</th><th>Thing</th></tr>
                <tr><td>1.1</td><td>some</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1.2</td><td>many</td></tr>
        </table>
    </li>
    <li>Item2</li>
            <table>
            <tr><th>Num</th><th>Thing</th></tr>
            <tr><td>2.1</td><td>few</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2.2</td><td>lots</td></tr>
        </table>
    <li>Item3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: `I'm wanting to do number of the table based on the parent li number.` Can you briefly Explain this Context?

Comment: It's essentially test steps that you would go through, the li would be what you are testing, ex Test Item 1, the table would then go through the test steps, ex 1.1 do this, 1.2 now add this, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH-TO-jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $("ol").each(function(indexOl, elemOl) {
        var liNr = 1;
        jQuery(elemOl).children("li").each(function(indexLi, elemLi) {
        var trNr = 1;
        jQuery(elemLi).find("tr").each(function(indexTr, elemTr){
            jQuery(elemTr).find("td:first").each(function(indexTd, elemTd){
            elemTd.innerHTML = "INSERTED: "+liNr+"."+trNr;
            ++trNr;
            });
        });
        ++liNr;
        });
    });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
    <li>Item1
    <table>
        <tr><th>Num</th><th>Thing</th></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>some</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>many</td></tr>
    </table>
    </li>
    <li>Item2
    <table>
        <tr><th>Num</th><th>Thing</th></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>few</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>lots</td></tr>
    </table>
    </li>
    <li>Item3</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

The same for a 3-level structure:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH-TO-jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $("ol:first").each(function(indexOl, elemOl) {
        var sectionNr = 1;
        jQuery(elemOl).children("li").each(function(indexLiSection, elemLiSection) {
        var subSectionNr = 1;
        jQuery(elemLiSection).children("ol").each(function(indexOlSubsection, elemOlSubsection){
            jQuery(elemOlSubsection).children("li").each(function(indexLiSubsection, elemLiSubsection) {
            var trNr = 1;
            jQuery(elemLiSubsection).find("tr").each(function(indexTr, elemTr){
                jQuery(elemTr).find("td:first").each(function(indexTd, elemTd){
                elemTd.innerHTML = "INSERTED: "+sectionNr+"."+subSectionNr+"."+trNr;
                ++trNr;
                });
            });
            ++subSectionNr;
            });
        });
        ++sectionNr;
        });
    });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
    <li>Section1
    <ol>
        <li>Subsection1.1
        <table>
            <tr><th>Num</th><th>Thing</th></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>some</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>many</td></tr>
        </table>
        </li>
        <li>Subsection1.2
        <table>
            <tr><th>Num</th><th>Thing</th></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>some</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>many</td></tr>
        </table>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Section2
    <ol>
        <li>Subsection2.1
        <table>
            <tr><th>Num</th><th>Thing</th></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>some</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>many</td></tr>
        </table>
        </li>
        <li>Subsection2.2
        <table>
            <tr><th>Num</th><th>Thing</th></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>some</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>many</td></tr>
        </table>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Section3
    <ol>
        <li>Subsection3.1
        <table>
            <tr><th>Num</th><th>Thing</th></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>some</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>many</td></tr>
        </table>
        </li>
        <li>Subsection3.2
        <table>
            <tr><th>Num</th><th>Thing</th></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>some</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>many</td></tr>
        </table>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was asking for.  I'm trying to modify it to go one more tier deeper in a list.  So something like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/3enCe/2/.  It would show 1.1.1

Comment: Your jsfiddle code does not show a 3-level example. Added code for such, hope it fits your requirements.

Comment: Sorry to bother you yet again, I need to make it a 4-level example, which I should have just said last time.  I keep trying to replicate what you did by adding another set of check children of the ol and li but it doesn't work.

Comment: I added the following around the tr part of the code with it's own counter and fixed which variable is used in it.
$(elemLiSubsection).children("ol").each(function(indexOlSubsubsection, elemOlSubsubsection){ 
   $(elemOlSubsubsection).children("li").each(function(indexLiSubsubsection, elemLiSubsubsection) {